# If I have to use jQuery 1.11.3, what version of jQuery UI should I use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a project that requires support for IE8, maybe even IE7, which is why I have to stick with jQuery 1.11.3. The frontend makes heavy use of jQuery UI. Can I use the latest version of jQuery UI, or should I resort to an older version? If so, which one?

Comment: download  jQuery UI, it comes with a compatible version of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If anyone is wondering, jQuery UI is currently bundled with jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: jquery ui wikipedia has a table but I don't think it is valid/ complete.

Answer (score 0):

get the latest jQuery UI (1.11.4 at the time of writting), it depends on JQuery 1.6+, so your version of jQuery 1.11.3 is covered.
http://jqueryui.com/download/